# Make one item of a flexbox half or a quarter size of other items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have 3 items in a flex box all set to flex: 1 how would I make one of them 1/2 to 1/4th the size of the others?

```css
.div {
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row;
}

div > * {
   background-color: lightblue;
   padding: 4px;
   flex: 1;
   border: 1px solid gray;
}

.smaller {
   flex: .5 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="smaller">3</div>
</div>
```

This seems to work here but it's not working in my project.

Is there a simpler example? Setting flex to anything other than "1" doesn't seem to work. I've read 5 articles on this and I don't know how those flex values work.

Comment: maybe `flex: .5 1 0;` instead of `flex: .5 1 auto;`

Comment: if it works here and not in your project than the problem is in your project not it the snippet

Comment: OK we are getting something, `flex: .5 1 0` works it seems. But what does it all mean Basil?

Comment: flex-basis need to be 0 so the content isn't considered when splitting the free space (like all the element will start at 0 width)

Comment: @dippas there was some other issues going on with the project, `.5 1 auto` works but `.5 1 0` is what I think I need.

Comment: the figure in the duplicate is all what you need to understand your error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying `flex: .5 1 0` should work. That should size it the way you want.